# Unable to locate element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, findelement

I'm trying to click on an accept cookies button while navigating a webpage using Selenium and Python.

[image: Pic of cookie button]

I've used inspect element to find the class name of the button, and then `.click()` in Python to click on it. It isn't a link, but if it were working the accept cookies pop-up would disappear, and it isn't.

[image: HTML on website for the button]

Instead, I'm getting this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".SubmitButton CookiePopup-button"}

Here is the code I am running:

```
cookie_button = driver.find_element("class name", "SubmitButton CookiePopup-button").click()
```

Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this, see if it works

```
cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.SubmitButton.CookiePopup-button").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there are spaces in the class attribute, to get around this you can instead search by using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `"class name"` and use this selector:

```
button[class='SubmitButton CookiePopup-button']
```

try and see if the below works:

```
cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='SubmitButton CookiePopup-button']").click()
```